# Drop rows from pandas dataframe based on other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I need your help please. I have a dataframe (500k rows) like this:

| account | category | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | cat1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 1234567 | cat1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 1234567 | cat1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-09 |
| 1234567 | cat2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 1234567 | cat2 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-08-09 |
| 7654321 | cat1 | 2021-03-01 | 2099-12-31 |
| 7654321 | cat2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-28 |
| 7654321 | cat2 | 2021-03-01 | 2099-12-31 |

Now I need to drop the 'oldest' rows where account and category are the same. Result should be like:

| account | category | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | cat1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-09 |
| 1234567 | cat2 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-08-09 |
| 7654321 | cat1 | 2021-03-01 | 2099-12-31 |
| 7654321 | cat2 | 2021-03-01 | 2099-12-31 |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ensure that datelike columns are of datetime dtype:

```
df['startdate']=pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'])
df['enddate']=pd.to_datetime(df['enddate'])
```

Finally use `sort_values()` and `drop_duplicates()`

```
df=(df.sort_values(by=['startdate','enddate'],ascending=False)
      .drop_duplicates(subset=['account','category'],ignore_index=True))
```

output of `df`:

```
    account     category    startdate   enddate
0   1234567     cat1    2021-06-01  2021-08-09
1   1234567     cat2    2021-05-01  2021-08-09
2   7654321     cat1    2021-03-01  2099-12-31
3   7654321     cat2    2021-03-01  2099-12-31
```